# Django: List Products of each Categories in a page

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a few categories and I would like to list the products per category in the format below (categories is an FK to products):

Category 1

*bunch of products*

....

Category N

*bunch of products*

I have tried many ways but so far I only get the categories but not the products to show in my HTML.

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('category_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    @property
    def get_products(self):
         return Products.objects.filter(category=self.title)

class Products(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_path, null=True, blank=True)
 blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='Category', blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #this
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default="male")

    objects = ProductManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product_detail', args=(self.id,))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
def categories_m(request):
    query_Set = models.Category.objects.all()
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(query_Set, 20)
    try:
        cat = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        cat = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        cat = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'products/categories.html', {'categories': cat})
```

html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% for category in categories %}
    <h1>{{ category }}</h1>
    {% for product in categories.get_products %}
        <p>{{ product }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be `category` instead of `categories` in your template. And in your model filter products by category title.

```
@property
def get_products(self):
     return Products.objects.filter(categories__title=self.title)
```

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

    {% block content %}
        {% for category in categories %}
        <h1> {{category}} </h1>

        {% for product in category.get_products %}
            <p> {{product}} </p>
        {% endfor %}

        {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: No, this does not work. I have tried this before. It throws : Cannot resolve keyword 'category' into field. Choices are: active, categories, categories_id, gender, id, image, title ....

Comment: @Inconnu In your model remove the `@property` decorator.

Comment: Did, you try importing `Category` and setting `query_Set = Category.objects.all()` ? I'm not sure that's reason, just saying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169462/discussion-between-md-khairul-basar-and-inconnu).

Answer (score 4):

You could remove the `related_name` attribute from your field

```
class Products(models.Model):
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And then in your template you can use `category.products_set.all`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

    {% block content %}
    {% for category in categories %}
        <h1>{{ category }}</h1>
        {% for product in category.products_set.all %}
            <p>{{ product }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Why he needs to remove `related_name` ?? He can use `category.Category.all`.

Comment: Hm... that might have been poor wording on my part: I meant that it is semantically more correct to define the `related_name` (or use the default) so that you can understand what type of object you are getting. Using `related_name='Category'` is a bit confusing because it does NOT return `Category` objects.

Comment: Oh, Yes. You are right. `related_name` should have been something related to `Product`.