# Django: List Items of each categories in a single page

Tags: python, django

I'm working on checklist app and each checklist have tasks with categories.

I would like to list the tasks per category in the format below:

```
Category 1
Task 1 of Category 1
Task 2 of Category 1

Category 2
Task 1 of Category 2
Task 2 of Category 2
```

I’ve tried this answer - [Django: List Products of each Categories in a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49948016/django-list-products-of-each-categories-in-a-page)

But always have a blank list without any errors..

```py
class Checklist(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
            ChecklistCategory,
            blank=True, 
            null=True,
            on_delete=models.SET_NULL
        )
    language = models.ForeignKey(
            ChecklistLanguage,
            blank=True,
            null=True,
            on_delete=models.SET_NULL
        )
    image = models.ImageField(
                upload_to='images/checklist/cover/%Y/%m/%d/',
                default='default_cover.png',
                blank=True,
                null=True
            )
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='checklist_likes', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-name']

    def get_like_url(self):
        return reverse('checklist_like_toggle_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('checklist_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = gen_slug(self.name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class ChecklistTaskCategory(models.Model):
    task_category_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task_category_name


class ChecklistTask(models.Model):
    task = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    checklist = models.ForeignKey(
            Checklist, 
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            blank=True, 
            null=True
        )
    task_category = models.ForeignKey(
        ChecklistTaskCategory,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    done = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='task_done', blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True, blank=True)

    def get_done_url(self):
        return reverse('task_done_toggle_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('checklist_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = gen_slug(self.task)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.task
```

```html
{% for task in tasks %}
                    <div class="custom-control custom-switch pt-3" data-aos="fade-left">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch{{ task.id }}">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch{{ task.id }}">{{ task.task }}</label>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
```

Comment: You need to show your view. And how have you "tried" that linked answer?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to add *related_name* to *task_category* field.

```
task_category = models.ForeignKey(
    ChecklistTaskCategory,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='tasks')
```

And add list of all category **ChecklistTaskCategory.objects.all()** to view context. And get list of tasks per each category in template.

```
{% for category in categories %}
  <div>{{ category.task_category_name }} </div>
    {% for task in category.tasks.all %}
    <div class="custom-control custom-switch pt-3" data-aos="fade-left">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch{{ task.id }}">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch{{ task.id }}">{{ task.task }}</label>
   </div>
 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Now i have another problem. All checklists have the same lists of tasks and tasks categories. But I need to show checklists with own tasks and tasks categories.